# Dividing responsibility between View and Template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-template-filters

There's a feature in Twitter called hashtags that extracts tags from messages.
For example, in

```
"Hey #guys, I love #stackoverflow"
```

`#guys` and `#stackoverflow` are clickable and lead to their own queries.

I'm building a similar app for training, and I wonder **where and when to actually inject links in the output**?

I grab all recent tweets:

```
def index(request):
    latest_tweets = Tweet.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                              { 'tweets': latest_tweets },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                              )
```

And in a block I render:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    <p>{{tweet.message}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But this of course only shows plain message, no links.
I want each `#tag` in `message` to be replaced with a link passing tag name in a query string to a view called `by_tag`.

**Does inserting `<a href="...">`s belong to `views.py`? Then what if I later decided this to be an AJAX link? Okay, seems like this belongs to templates. But how do I do such a complex replacement with routing from a template? Should I write a custom template filter?**

Just for the reference, a `Tweet` contains its `Tag`s in a field called `tags`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something similar last week and wrote a quick custom [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs) to scan text looking for mentions and hashtags and wrap them in links.

https://gist.github.com/1023144

It makes sense to do this at the template level as you are performing HTML markup/replacement.

Generally, your views perform routing logic, i.e. taking the url, retrieving and aggregating the necessary data, and rendering the template.

If there is any associated logic you need to perform on a model (i.e. compare to tweets for example), it is a good idea to put this in Model functions, or Model Managers, as it is logic tied to you Models and Database.

Any logic in at the template level should generally address the structuring and displaying the data it has received from the view.

Sometimes though, you might want to perform some logic at the template level so that it can be reused across different views (like grabbing the top 10 most popular tags for example). This is a good time to create a template tag to perform the logic (and it's also nice and reuseable)

Anyway, place that code in:

```
yourapp/templatetags.py
```

and in the template:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    <p>{{ tweet.message|twittify }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for a wonderful explanation and for a code snippet. Now I'm wondering: is it OK to hardcore the application links in templates? For example, in ASP .NET MVC instead of specifying URL like `/product/create/` we call `Url.Route ('Product', 'Create')` which reads routing table and gives URL by controller and action name. How is this usually done in django? (considering I want links to go to `by_tag` view with `name` parameter)

Comment: Yes you can get that functionality. If you want to lookup the URL in a view or in a piece of application logic, use the reverse function: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) or if you want to achieve the same in your template use the "url" template tag: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url). If you can't get it working, open up a new question and you will be able to get help

Comment: these links are all I need and I swear I could've found them if I googled harder. Thanks a lot for your help!